# Getting all PDF files from internal as well as external storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, storage

I want to show all file in internal as well as external  storage in flutter into ListView.
But when I try get files from this directory

```
late var directory;
  List<dynamic> file = [];
  Future<void> _listofFiles() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if(status.isDenied ) print('isDenied');
    if(status.isGranted ) print('isGranted');
    directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    // directory = '/storage/emulated/0/';
    setState(() {
      file = directory.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
    });
  }
```

and show in ListView there is nothing

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _listofFiles(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
            return Text('Loading');
          }else {
            print('This directory: ${directory} , ${file.length}');
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: file.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(file[index].toString());
              }),
          );}}),
```

I check for storage perrmission is ok and the results path is :

```
I/flutter (21163): isGranted
I/flutter (21163): This directory: /data/user/0/com.example.librera_reader_clone/app_flutter , 0
```